# Como fechar um modal somente pelos botôes?

Tags: html, bootstrap, modal

O título já é alto explicativo. Mas eu gostaria de saber como é que eu fecho um modal somente pelo botão de close e pelo "x" da janela, não permitindo que o usuário clique no fundo preto ao redor da janela de pop up para fechar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a opção `backdrop` com `data-backdrop="static"`. Conforme consta da [documentação oficial](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options), essa opção faz com que a janela *modal* não feche com o *click*, só com os botões.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/99/

Comment: Bem isso mesmo obrigado cara!

Comment: Adicione também a propriedade `data-keyboard="false"` para evitar que seja fechado com o teclado.

Comment: Verdade eu acabei de verificar esse problema kkkk obrigada também Pedro!

Comment: Quanto a documentação, como disse o Maurivan sempre vale uma leitura: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Comment: Boa Sorte Pedro!